# Calling mean() Function Without Removing Non-Numeric Columns In Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

fertilityRates = pd.read_csv('fertility_rate.csv')

fertilityRatesRowCount = len(fertilityRates.axes[0])

fertilityRates.head(fertilityRatesRowCount)
```

[image: Dataframe]

I have found a way to find the mean for each row over columns 1960-1969, but would like to do so without removing the column called "Country".

The following is what is outputted after I execute the following commands:

```
Mean1960To1970 = fertilityRates.iloc[:, 1:11].mean(axis=1)

Mean1960To1970
```

[image: After Calling mean()]

Comment: Can you explain your question more? Because currently, you are not removing the first column. What do you not understand, or what problem want you to solve?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pandas.DataFrame.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) to select a range of years (e.g `"1960":"1968"` means from 1960 to 1968).

Try this :

```
Mean1960To1968 = (
                    fertilityRates[["Country"]]
                        .assign(Mean= fertilityRates.loc[:, "1960":"1968"].mean(axis=1))
                 )
```

##### # Output :

```
print(Mean1960To1968)

                Country      Mean
0                _World  5.004444
1           Afghanistan  7.450000
2               Albania  5.913333
3               Algeria  7.635556
4                Angola  7.030000
5   Antigua and Barbuda  4.223333
6            Arab World  7.023333
7             Argentina  3.073333
8               Armenia  4.133333
9                 Aruba  4.044444
10            Australia  3.167778
11              Austria  2.715556
```